# Active jquery function when ctrl+alt is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I want to active the `draggable` and `resizable` function in jquery when (and only) the ctrl+alt button is pressed and disable when it's released and I wrote this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
    #para {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .ui-resizable-helper {
      border: 2px dotted #00F;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        $("#para").draggable();
        $("#para").resizable({
          helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="para" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h1 contenteditable>Header</h1>
    <hr />
    <p contenteditable>paragraph</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

After I finished this code I tried to press ctrl+alt in the browser but it doesn't work, I've removed the `if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey)` logic part and it works successfully but as I replace the logic statement back there it doesn't work

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an event handler to catch the keypresses.

You can initialize the plugin as `disabled` and then `enable` it when the keys are pressed, and `disable` it again when the keys are released

```js
 $(function() {
    $("#para").draggable({
        disabled : true
    });

    $("#para").resizable({
        helper   : "ui-resizable-helper",
        disabled : true
    });

    $(document).on({
        keydown : function(e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey) {
                $("#para").draggable( "enable" );
                $("#para").resizable( "enable" );
            }
        }, 
        keyup : function() {
            $("#para").draggable( "disable" );
            $("#para").resizable( "disable" );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
    #para {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .ui-resizable-helper {
      border: 2px dotted #00F;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="para" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h1 contenteditable>Header</h1>
    <hr />
    <p contenteditable>paragraph</p>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```